# Table with figures inside a table

Tags: tables, includegraphics

I'm trying to put a figure (with \tabular) inside a table (\tabular):

I've tried the code:

```
\begin{tabular}{cc}
    \begin{figure}
        \begin{tabular}{ccc}
            \includegraphics[width=0.16\linewidth]{example-image} &  
            \includegraphics[width=0.16\linewidth]{example-image} &
            \includegraphics[width=0.16\linewidth]{example-image}
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{Some text}
    \end{figure}
    &
    \begin{figure}
        \begin{tabular}{ccc}
            \includegraphics[width=0.16\linewidth]{example-image} &  
            \includegraphics[width=0.16\linewidth]{example-image} &
            \includegraphics[width=0.16\linewidth]{example-image}
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{Some text}
    \end{figure}
\end{tabular}
```

and

```
\begin{table}{cc}
    \begin{figure}
        \begin{subfigure}
            \includegraphics[width=0.16\linewidth]{example-image}
        \end{subfigure}
        \begin{subfigure}
            \includegraphics[width=0.16\linewidth]{example-image}
        \end{subfigure}
                \begin{subfigure}
            \includegraphics[width=0.16\linewidth]{example-image}
        \end{subfigure}
        \caption{Some text}
    \end{figure}
&
    \begin{figure}
        \begin{subfigure}
            \includegraphics[width=0.16\linewidth]{example-image}
        \end{subfigure}
        \begin{subfigure}
            \includegraphics[width=0.16\linewidth]{example-image}
        \end{subfigure}
                \begin{subfigure}
            \includegraphics[width=0.16\linewidth]{example-image}
        \end{subfigure}
        \caption{Some text}
    \end{figure}
\end{table}
```

both of these code blocks make an error.

I'm trying to make it look like this:
[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to TeX:SE!

With help of `tabularx` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[ht]
    \setkeys{Gin}{width=0.32\linewidth}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} XX @{}}
    \includegraphics{example-image-duck}\hfill 
    \includegraphics{example-image-duck}\hfill
    \includegraphics{example-image-duck}
%
   \caption{Some text}
    &   \includegraphics{example-image-duck}\hfill
        \includegraphics{example-image-duck}\hfill
        \includegraphics{example-image-duck} 
%
        \caption{Some text}
\end{tabularx}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Although it was not the answer I was looking for. It definately works in a `\documentclass{article}` environment, so therefore it does answer the question. However, I want it to work in a `\documentclass{tikzposter}` environment. That was my fault, I've now reposted a new question. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution that doesn't require any `tabular`-like structures.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{graphicx} % for '\includegraphics' macro
\usepackage{caption}  % for '\captionof' macro
\begin{document}

\noindent     
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=0.32\linewidth]{example-image}\hfill  
    \includegraphics[width=0.32\linewidth]{example-image}\hfill
    \includegraphics[width=0.32\linewidth]{example-image}
\captionof{figure}{Some text}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=0.32\linewidth]{example-image}\hfill  
    \includegraphics[width=0.32\linewidth]{example-image}\hfill
    \includegraphics[width=0.32\linewidth]{example-image}
\captionof{figure}{Some more text}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

---

Alternatively, if you prefer to place the images in a `figure` float, you could employ the following code:

```
\begin{figure}   
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=0.32\linewidth]{example-image}\hfill  
    \includegraphics[width=0.32\linewidth]{example-image}\hfill
    \includegraphics[width=0.32\linewidth]{example-image}
\caption{Some text}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=0.32\linewidth]{example-image}\hfill  
    \includegraphics[width=0.32\linewidth]{example-image}\hfill
    \includegraphics[width=0.32\linewidth]{example-image}
\caption{Some more text}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```